# Linux loadable module precise timing

Tags: c, linux, linux-device-driver

I have written a linux loadable kernel module to handle a custom serial protocol over a GPIO pin to communicate with an embedded device.

I used this approach in order to get more priority, and so more precision, in control GPIO transitions. I have used the udelay/mdelay functions inside linx/delay.h.

I have implemented an interrupt handler on an arduino board to printout, by the serial debug interface, the time between the GPIO transitions, and the timing seems not be so precise as I expected (please don't take in account the delay introduced by the debug interface, the same issue is reproducibile at lower speeds).

Could you point me on how to discover why it happens, or how to get a better way, inside the linux module, to activate/deactivate the GPIO line at precise intervals?

Thank you so much!
Antonio

**Edit:**

I would provide some additional information. The devices are:

1. Transmitter: [C.H.I.P.](https://getchip.com/pages/chip) : CPU Arm 1GHz, OS Ubuntu 15
2. Receiver: Arduino NANO

I would ask you also, **how the default UART driver can transmit at a fixed/precise time rate**.

Thank you again!

Comment: From linux/delay.h header: *“Please note that ndelay(), udelay() and mdelay() may return early for several reasons…”* You might look into those, as those reasons are very common: cpu frequency scaling, cache coming into play, delay too large or too small.

Comment: (If you are building some device that has true realtime needs and does not target the general public, perhaps you could consider running a realtime os instead or below your environment; things such as RTAI or RTLinux).

Comment: You can't do this in Linux. Linux is not a RTOS. Choose Zephyr project for example.

Comment: Instead of down voting could you suggest useful alternatives? The standard UART driver is an example of a precise timing. How is it implemented?

Comment: It really depends on many things: architecture of the processor, hardware, the interval tick of the scheduler etc...

Comment: I edited the main post with more information...

Comment: Please show your code. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).*

Comment: @AntonioPetricca> I might be wrong but I believe those days UART in computers are more of the 16550 kind. Those do not need precise time rate, they include receive and transmit buffers and only need attention from the cpu every now and then. They were introduced precisely because achieving correct timing for a 8250 was pretty much impossible in a multitasked OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution by using the [completion APIs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/scheduler/completion.txt).

Thank you anyway.

Comment: I opened a new thread on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44693693/a-hr-timers-precision-study-case .